# How to access a particular array (after a loop)

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, indexing

After running a loop which multiplies an entire 2D array by a scalar, I would like to access a particular array outside the loop. Say that the loop produces 20 arrays, I would like to access, for arguments sake, the 10th array.

I have tried indexing, but that gives me an exact value within an array. So say we had an array A, then A[1,2] would return the value within A when i = 1, and j = 2. I want to retrieve a whole array.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.arange(0,10,1)

b = np.arange(0,10,1)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(a,b)


print("Below is X")
print(X)

print("Below is Y")
print(Y)


for i in range(len(X)):
    Z = i*X
    print(i)
    print(Z)


#How do I now access the ith Z array outside the loop above?
```

I would like to be able to say, 'print ith Z array'.

Comment: something is unclear. inside the loop, you override the entire `Z` array (set it as an integer). Maybe you meant something a little different.

Comment: Now edited, don't know why I initialised Z to then overwrite it.

Comment: now you are assigning a new single value to Z in every single step (for i in range..)

Comment: the shape of variable X, Y and Z is (10, 10), as above user said your Z value is replace, if you want 1st array of Z then use Z[0], if you want particular value of 0th array use Z[0][1] and so on.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, sorry. Is the issue that I keep replacing the previous value of Z each time I run through a loop? I'd like to multiply my entire Z array by the scalar i . If I do Z[i] = i * X[i] then all my Z arrays are the same. My end goal is to have many graphs for different times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually you don't need to iterate over the `range(len(X))` of your array, since numpy arrays can be processed via vectorization.

Check the following code snippet:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(0,10,1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(a,a)
Z = X*a

print(X)
#    [[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
#     ...
#     [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]]

print(Y)
#    [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#     ...
#     [9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9]]

print(Z)
#    [[ 0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81]
#     ...
#     [ 0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81]]

print(Z[0])
#     [ 0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81]
```

As you don't need to generate a 10x10 array `Z`, you can also get this vector short via:

```
print(X[0]*a)
#     [ 0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access to any ith Z array after the loop y suggest you to create a list and save all the arrays. Something like this:

```html
Z = []
for i in range(len(X)):
    Z.append(i*X)
    print(i)
    print(Z)

print(Z[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Appending to `numpy` array in a loop is very inefficient (quadratic cost) because you are making a full copy of the data each `append`. Therefore we will use basic `python` list, and then convert it into `numpy`

```
i=0
Z=[]
while i < len(X):
    Z.append(i*X)
    i+=1
#     print(i)
#     print(Z)
Z = np.asarray(Z)
```

Finally, you simply pass the one-dimensional index to access the sub-arrays:

```
Z[3]
```

Comment: thank you! Is there a reason why a while loop would be recommended here ahead of a for loop?

Comment: You are welcome! No, there was any reasoning for that. Just used a different loop structure